# Cant figure out how to deal with this set of HTTP requests in an MVC4 controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I am trying tt simulate a server that has to respond to these requests (I have no control over this scheme) ....

```
http://localhost:61728/?method=query&rfid=1382629068&questions=true&responseOnly=false
http://localhost:61728/?method=update&questions=true&responseOnly=false&xml="...."
http://localhost:61728/?method=ping
```

So I have 5 parameters in the string `method`, `rfid`, `questions`, `responseOnly`, `xml`. And depending on the method, some of the other parameters may be missing. (Missing boolean parameters should be treated as false).

I am trying to figure out how to deal with these 3 request types in an MVC4 Controller.

I have tried many variations inc the below. Here, I am attempting to match the first request with a route and have created an action method for it. I doesnt work `The resource cannot be found`.  However I realise I dont understand properly how routes and action method work (e.g. can you only use them if your url is of the form: `/..../..../.....`, or can you use them with query strings?)

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Query",
   url: "{method}/{rfid}/{questions}/{responseOnly}/",
   defaults: new { controller = "TicketMachine", action = "Query", questions = false, responseOnly = false},
   constraints: new { controller = "TicketMachine", method="query" }
);
```

---

```
public class TicketMachineController : Controller
{
public ActionResult Query(String method, long rfid, bool questions, bool responseOnly)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("method=" + method + ", rfid=" + rfid + ", questions=" + questions + ", responseOnly=" + responseOnly);
    String ticketXml = TicketStore.GenerateTicketXml(rfid);
    return Content(ticketXml, "text/xml");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "Query",
url: "?",
defaults: new { controller = "TicketMachine", action = "Query"},
);
```

this should work on your route provider. the controller should work as it is. You make just one controller, and make the properties optional.

```
public ActionResult Query(String method, long rfid =" ", bool questions =true, bool responseOnly = true, int someOtherVariable = 10){}
```

after this in the controller you check the method and so on....

Comment: Thanks very much. That worked. (I had to set `url: ""` as it didnt like the `?`.)